# Regular expression to match from end

Tags: php, regex

Hello i need to match an string from end (right to left).For example From the string hello999hello888hello**777**last i need to get **777** between last set of `hello` and `last` .Which works correctly from below code.

```
$game = "hello999hello888hello777last";
preg_match('/hello(\d+)last$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match);
```

But , instead of 777 , i have mixture of symbols numbers and alphabets , suppose for example From string `hello999hello888hello0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwantlast` i need to take `0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwant`.

```
$game = "hello999hello888hello0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwantlast";
preg_match('/hello(.*?)last$/', $game, $match);
print_r($match);
```

why is that above code returing `999hello888hello0string#@$@#%#$%#$%#$%@iwant` .What is the correct procedure to read from right to left other then string reverse method.

Note : i want to match multiple string using preg_match_all aswel.for example

```
$string = 'hello999hello888hello0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwantlast

hello999hello888hello02ndstring%@iwantlast';

preg_match_all('/.*hello(.*?)last$/', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

which must return `0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwant` and `02ndstring%@iwant`

Comment: hint: .* is greedy, which means that it _eats_ as much as it can within a matching regex

Comment: Why do you split the strings that way? In my opinion this is an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your regex like this:

```
/.*hello(.*?)last$/
```

Explanation:

```
.*     eat everything before the last 'hello' (it's greedy)
hello  eat the last hello
(.*?)  capture the string you want
last   and finally, stop at 'last'
$      anchor to end
```

The `?` is actually unneccessary, because if you're anchoring to the end you want the last `last` anyway. Remove the `$` if you want to match something like `helloMatch this textlastDon't match this`.

For multiline, just remove the `$` as well.

Comment: Thank you.But its not working to match multiple match in string...please see my edited questions.

Comment: @VishnuVishwa So, you want to match from the last hello before a newline, to `last\n`? I am editing my answer now

Comment: @TimS. What do you mean?

Comment: @Doorknob try matching the string: `hellogoodbyelast.`. It won't, because there are characters after `last`.

Comment: @TimS. I believe that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @VishnuVishwa Ok, edited for multiline as well (I actually don't know PHP, I just know regex, so I had to test a lot `:P`)

Answer (score 2):

This regex will do what you want (including matching multiple times):

```
/.*hello(.*)last/
```

Working example:

```
$string = 'hello999hello888hello0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwantlast

hello999hello888hello02ndstring%@iwantlast';

preg_match_all('/.*hello(.*)last/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches)

/**   

Output: 


array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "hello999hello888hello0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwantlast"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "hello999hello888hello02ndstring%@iwantlast"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "0string#@$@#anysymbols%@iwant"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "02ndstring%@iwant"
  }
}

*/
```

Comment: Thanks :) working but answered first by Darknoob.anyway +1 :)

Comment: this will still match `helloSome text to matchlastOh no, extra text after the end`

Comment: what do you mean doorknob ? you too answered same

Comment: No, I meant if you give it a string `hello blah blah blah last oops` it will still match `blah blah blah`, even when there is an `oops` at the end.

Comment: Yes,I see, but `last` was the final delimiter, everything after it is ignored whether it be `\n`, some text, or anything else. After it finds `last` it will go on to try and find another match (i.e. starts looking for `hello` again)